# WPF: Controls in a class do not show up on Canvas

Tags: wpf, canvas, interface, observablecollection

### The background of the problem

I have a Class that it inherits from Main Window and implements the custom-made IProcessSimulator interface, because I want to use differnt classes in the future.
At the moment, the class stores definitions for a Grid element and a TextBlock (and also its formatting, but only for the time being).

My idea was to create different instances of this (and any other future) class *on runtime*, so I created an Observable collection of type IProcessSimulator to store them. I have a Canvas and I wanted to add these class-defined elements to the Canvas.

### Problem

The main problem is that no matter what properties I set, the controls do not show up on the Canvas, actually, Visual Studio doesn't even let me add the instance to the canvas saying that *Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget* although I did not add it to the Canvas anywhere else. My suspicion is that this has to do with my interface-type collection given that **canvasName.Children.Add()** in fact adds my element to another collection (UIElement Collection), but I'm relatively new to WPF. Previously, I tried to assign attributes like Width and Hight through the constructor of my class, but I also tried to invoke a function to no avail.

### Relevant Code Snippets

## Class

```
class ProcessWindow : MainWindow,  IProcessSimulator
{
    #region Implement: ProcessSimulator
    string content = "<Add content>";
    public string Content
    {
        get
        {
            return content;
        }

        set
        {
            content = value;
        }
    }

    string title = "<Add  Title>";
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return title;
        }

        set
        {
            title = value;
        }
    }

    ProcessType type = ProcessType.Default;
    public ProcessType Type
    {
        get
        {
            return type;
        }
    }

    #endregion



    //constructor for my class
    public ProcessWindow()
    {
        SetMainGrid();
        SetTitleBlock();
    }

    public Grid windowGrid = new Grid();
    public void SetMainGrid()
    {
        //give elements some props for testing purps
        windowGrid.Name = "MainGrid";
        windowGrid.Height = 200;
        windowGrid.Width = 200;
        windowGrid.Background = Brushes.Black;
        windowGrid.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);

       //this would be the place for MainCanvas.Children.Add(windowGrid)
        Canvas.SetLeft(MainCanvas, 10);
        Canvas.SetTop(MainCanvas, 10);

    }
    public TextBlock titleBlock = new TextBlock();

    public void SetTitleBlock()
    {
        //place for doing another "adding"
        Canvas.SetLeft(titleBlock, 0);
        Canvas.SetTop(titleBlock, 0);

        //give elements some props for testing purps
        //I even tried swapping the order of "Canvas-commands" and property giving
        titleBlock.Name = "TitleBlockName";
        titleBlock.Text = Title;
        titleBlock.Height = 30;
        titleBlock.Width = 30;
        titleBlock.Background = Brushes.Black;
    }
```

## Main Window

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<IProcessSimulator> ProcessElements { get; set; }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ProcessElements = new ObservableCollection<IProcessSimulator>();
    }

    private void Default_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //acc to the simple test, the collection is addable and the elements are stored in it
        ProcessElements.Add(new ProcessWindow());
        //ProcessElements[0].Initialize();
        MessageBox.Show("Element number" + ProcessElements.Count.ToString());
    }
```

I'm sure it is some basic error on my side, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried using a component spy app (e.g. Snoop) to see if your controls are rendering?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Well, they don't seem to render on the Canvas. I think this is because I do not add my controls to it, but as I specified it above, VS doesn't even let me to.

Comment: I don't see your XAML, but in SetMainGrid, shouldn't you be setting Canvas.SetX on the windowGrid, not MainCanvas?

Comment: Not sure if the MainWindow base class of ProcessWindow is identical to the other MainWindow class you're showing, but if it's derived from Window, you can't add instances of it to a Canvas. In WPF, Windows can't be child elements.

Comment: **UPDATE:** I let both of my declarations (e.g. public Grid windowGrid ) in the class *outside* of the function, but put my instantiations (e.g. windowGrid = new Grid() ) into the function. This way, VS allows me to add the instatns of the class with the two instants of these elements in the ObservableCollection.
@ericrtodd: yes, you are right, i should have. I did in the case of the grid, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem, so should anyone face the same problem in the future, I post my solution here.

## The solution

The main problem was, as @Clemens pointed it out to me, that a *Window* cannot be made child of the Main Window (I'm still curious as to *why*, but that's another question). As my custom class inherited from the MainWindow, it became a Window element as well.

But then I had to figure out how to add elements to a Canvas without using the Canvas, which was easy: I pass the Canvas itself as an argument to the constructor of my class, so this way I can call it whenever I need.
Here is the code with a little modification, so now I place the grid wherever the mouse points at the time of creating the element:

## The function responsible for setting the elements

```
       public void SetMainGrid(Canvas canvasOnWhichElementsAreDisplayed)
    {
        windowGrid = new Grid();
        canvasOnWhichElementsAreDisplayed.Children.Add(windowGrid);
        var mousePosition = Mouse.GetPosition(canvasOnWhichElementsAreDisplayed);
        Canvas.SetLeft(windowGrid, mousePosition.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(windowGrid, mousePosition.Y);
        windowGrid.Name = "MainGrid";
        windowGrid.Height = 200;
        windowGrid.Width = 200;
        windowGrid.Background = Brushes.Black;
    }
```

## The function handling the click event

```
private void Default_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessElements.Add(new ProcessWindow(MainCanvas));
        MessageBox.Show("Element number" + ProcessElements.Count.ToString());
    }
```